# Nested Loop using Return Pattern

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can explain to me how to create a nested loop using the Return pattern.

In my code below I return a 'dialog' array. For each item in the dialog array I want to call my 'loadAnswers' method and show the user a list of possible answers for the piece of dialog.

At the moment I'm returning the same set of answers for every piece of dialog, which is not what I want. i've hardcoded '1000' into my code below, but it should be data.DialogueID.

Thanks
Melt

```
my.vm = (function () { 
    dialog = ko.observableArray([]),
    answers = ko.observableArray([]),
    loaddialogueCallback = function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (data) {
            dialog.push(new my.Dialog1()
                 .dialogueId    (data.DialogueID)
                 .sortId        (data.SortID)
                 .picId         (data.CharacterID)
                 .picDesc       (data.CharacterDescription)
                 .pic           (data.CharacterPhoto)
                 .beforedialogue(data.BeforeDialogue)
                 .dialogue      (data.Dialogue)
                 .afterdialogue (data.AfterDialogue)
             );
        });
      },
   loadAnswersCallback = function (data) {
         data.forEach(function (data) {
             answers.push(new my.Answer()
              .answerid(data.AnswerId)
              .answer(data.Answer)
              .correct(data.Correct)
              );
         });
     },
   loadDialogue = function () {
        my.DataService.getDialogue(my.vm.loadDialogueCallback);
    },
   loadAnswers = function () {
        my.DataService.getAnswersList(1000,my.vm.loadAnswersCallback);
      };

    return {            
        Dialog: dialog,
        loadDialogueCallback: loadDialogueCallback,
        loadDialogue: loadDialogue,
        Answers:answers,
        loadAnswersCallback: loadAnswersCallback,
        loadAnswers:loadAnswers,     
    };      
})();

my.vm.loadAnswers();
my.vm.loadDialogue();

ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

MY VIEW

```
    <!-- Loop through Dialog  -->
    <div id="Dblock" data-bind='template: { foreach: Dialog, }'>
        <!-- Dialog Data is Here-->
        <!-- The Answers -->
        <span id="answers" data-bind='foreach:$root.Answers'>
            <a id="answer" data-bind='text:answer, click: function () { myanswer($parent.dialogue(),answer(),$parent.dialogueId()) }'></a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I wonder if a Mod could fix my code please...all the code for MY VIEW is not showing..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an answers array to your Dialog object, and either modify your getDialogue service to return the answers for that dialogue or make a call to get the answers for a dialogue when the dialog is.

Your answers span would then be:

```
    <span id="answers" data-bind='foreach: answers'>
```